# Add css file to layout not working

Tags: magento2, layout, css, less

I try to add a css file to a new layout for a cms page (magento 2):
src/app/design/frontend/NAME/default/Magento_Theme/page_layout/lpmdd-without-header.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<layout xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_layout.xsd">
    <head>
        <css src="css/lpmdd/lpmdd.css" />
    </head>
    <update handle="1column"/>

    <referenceContainer name="header.container" remove="true"/>
    <referenceContainer name="breadcrumbs" remove="true" />
    <referenceContainer name="page-bottom" remove="true" />
    <referenceContainer name="reassurance-container" remove="true"/>
</layout>
```

I have created lpmdd.less located in src/app/design/frontend/NAME/default/Magento_Theme/web/css/lpmdd/lpmdd.less

I try to clean cache  and running `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f`

And I try to change

```
<css src="Magento_Theme::css/lpmdd/lpmdd.css" />
```

but it doesn't work, do you have any idea?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use `<css src="Magento_Theme::css/lpmdd/lpmdd.css"/>` instead of `<css src="css/lpmdd/lpmdd.css"`
2. Run the following commands to clear static content and re-deploy static content for frontend:

```
rm -rf var/view_preprocessed/pub/static/frontend/
rm -rf pub/static/frontend/ 
bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f --area frontend
```

3. You can't declare a CSS file in `page_layout` file, you should declare it in a `layout` file.

As you need to add a CSS file to a CMS page, you can create a selectable layout file for CMS pages, then declare the CSS file there. Take a look at this post https://magetu.com/how-to-add-a-selectable-layout-to-cms-page-in-magento-2

4. Finally, clear `layout` cache type to see the result: `bin/magento cache:clean layout`

Comment: If this answer works as your expected, please mark it as **accepted**. That indicates your issue is solved and makes it easier for others with the same issue to find a verified answer.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but unfortunately it does not work

Comment: I tested it before posting the answer for you. Are you sure the site loads your CSS file after you added it to the layout xml?

Comment: A css file it's create in pub/static/frontend .. Just the layout does not load the file there is no line in the header that matches my file

Comment: I need to add my css only for the layout in question and thus be able to use it when creating new pages in BO

Comment: I know, I've updated my answer, please take a look. Let me know if you face any issues.